# Problem Lenovo G780 Windows 7 + Ubuntu does not work

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, partitioning, windows-7, lenovo

I am using Windows 7 in my laptop Lenovo G780 and I want to install Ubuntu 14.04 as a dual boot. Windows 7 works correctly, so I created a partition in my hard drive, changed the bios (I know there is an option in Lenovo's computers that make sure that some programs install correcly or something like that) and run the Ubuntu installation without errors.

The problem is the following: It does not appear any option about installing ubuntu and windows at the same time and there is no evidence of the windows installation or the partition I created.

Can anybody help me?

Thanks.

Comment: Please be more precise in your description of the problem. If necessary, post screen shots. Some types of partition table problems can make Ubuntu report that a disk has no partitions at all. If that's the problem, you should correct those problems. Also, creating new partitions for Ubuntu from within Windows is a ***BIG*** mistake that can cause serious data corruption. OTOH, it could be you simply need to use the "Something Else" partitioning option, which enables you to manually partition the disk. There are lots of tutorials describing how to do this.

Answer (score -2):

Delete the partition you created manually in Windows Disk Manager and when you have only Windows 7 installed on the drive with no other free partitions available it will ask you :)

You can install it inside Windows with Wubi (although it is an old method of installing) if you are having problems, also when you install ubuntu it is during the instalation where it asks you to erase the full disk or to share space with your Windows partition, good luck.

Comment: Yeah, I know it should ask if I want to share the space, here is the problem, it does not ask me xD But I will try to instal it with Wubi. Thanks ^^ I will tell later if it has worked out.

Comment: It doesnt ask you because you have manually created the partition, delete the partition you created manually in Windows Disk Manager and when you have only Windows 7 installed on the drive with no other free partitions available it will ask you :)

Comment: Ok, I am on it :D

Comment: WUBI is deprecated and limited. I strongly advise against using it.

Comment: At least it has worked for him, my solution is valid, I suggest you don't negative vote me when I have given a valid solution

Comment: Yeah, but **`wubi` is deprecated and hasn't been maintained for a long time** but your answer, on the other hand, *will still be here* for a long time, so the downvotes are not directed to you personally, but to the future readers of the answer.